# Calling a function that's stored in a map

Tags: elixir, anonymous-function

I'm new to Elixir, so still trying to properly understand how pattern matching works. I have a function that receives a `map` as an argument. This function may or may not have an `icon` key where `icon` should be a `function`.

- When there's an `icon` key, then I'd like to call it with a value because it's a function.
- When there's no `icon` key, then I'd like to have a default value.

I thought the code below would work but it didn't:

```elixir
defp get_icon(%{:icon => icon}), do: icon(@icon_size)
defp get_icon(_), do: Icon.default_icon(@icon_size)
```

When I try to call `icon(@icon_size)`, I get the following error message: `undefined function icon/1 (expected HelloWeb.Components.Button to define such a function or for it to be imported, but none are available)`.

I thought maybe I needed to pass the arity to `icon` like this: `&icon/1` but, then, I got another error saying `& is not allowed in matches`.

Is it possible to do what I'm trying to accomplish here or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: _Sidenote:_ the idiomatic syntax for atom keys in a map would be `%{icon: icon}` not `%{:icon => icon}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`icon(@icon_size)` is the syntax for a named function. It will look for the `icon/1` named function in the current *context* (e. g. your current module or in your imports.)

When calling an anonymous function, you need to add a dot:

```elixir
icon.(@icon_size)
```

The capture operator `&` is to take a named function and make an anonymous function from it, so this is the opposite of what you wanted to achieve here:

```elixir
f = &String.upcase/1
# is the same as
f = fn x -> String.upcase(x) end
```

You can see more information in the [`Function` module documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Function.html) or the [getting started guide](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/modules-and-functions.html).